# Behavior of Python numpy tofile and fromfile when saving int16

Tags: python, numpy

After appending data to an empty array and verifying it's shape, I use tofile to save it.  When I read it back with fromfile, the shape is much larger (4x).

```
# Create empty array
rx_data = np.empty((0), dtype='int16')

# File name to write data
file_name = "Test_file.bin"

# Generate two sinewaves and add to rx_data array in interleaved fashion
for i in range(100):
    I = np.sin(2*3.14*(i/100))
    rx_data = np.append(rx_data, I)
    Q = np.cos(2*3.14*(i/100))
    rx_data = np.append(rx_data, Q)
print(rx_data.shape)

# Write array to .bin file
rx_data.tofile(file_name)


# Read back data from the .file
s_interleaved = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=np.int16)
print(s_interleaved.shape)
```

The above code returns (200) before the array is saved, but return 800 when the array is read back in.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Just use `s_interleaved = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=int)` or `s_interleaved = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=float)` . I think it is happening because python `int` and `float` expand to accomodate any integer or floating point number, where as `np.int` or `np.float` have different behaviour. Try using `np.int32`, np.float64` etc. It's called an overflow error. [you might want to read this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors)

Comment: Make sure you understand what's being saved, not just the `shape` but also the `dtype`.  The load needs to have a matching `dtype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rx_data` has a float64 data type before you save it. This is because `I` and `Q` are float64 arrays, so when you use `np.append`, the type will be promoted to be compatible with the float64 values.

Also, populating an array using `np.append` is an anti-pattern in numpy. It's common to do in standard python, but with numpy, it is often better to create an array of the shape and data type you need, then to fill in the values in the `for` loop. This is better because you only need to create the array *once*. With `np.append`, you create a new copy every time you call it.

```py
rx_data = np.empty(200, dtype="float64")
for i in range(200):
    rx_data[i] = np.sin(...)
```

---

Here is code that works, because it uses float64. But this pattern should be avoided in general. Prefer pre-allocating an array and replacing the values in the for loop.

```py
# Create empty array
rx_data = np.empty((0), dtype='int16')

# File name to write data
file_name = "Test_file.bin"

# Generate two sinewaves and add to rx_data array in interleaved fashion
for i in range(100):
    I = np.sin(2*3.14*(i/100))
    rx_data = np.append(rx_data, I)
    Q = np.cos(2*3.14*(i/100))
    rx_data = np.append(rx_data, Q)
print(rx_data.shape)

# Write array to .bin file
print("rx_data data type:", rx_data.dtype)
rx_data.tofile(file_name)


# Read back data from the .file
s_interleaved = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=np.float64)
print(s_interleaved.shape)

# Test that the arrays are equal.
np.allclose(rx_data, s_interleaved)  # True
```

Comment: This is due to overflow error i guess. [Here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors)

Comment: Just using a normal `int` or `float` for dtype is sufficient as python int or float accomodate and has built-ins to handle overflow

Comment: I think that it is because `np.append` will find the best datatype to store both the original values and new values. In the OP's case, that would be float64.

Comment: True. But, simple built-in python dtypes work perfectly. Infact they state it in the manual. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html

Comment: Better not to use those precision types of np unless doing something very specific or scientific i would say. They sometimes messes things up pretty bad and difficult to find for most circumstances